# How do I align extruded faces perpendicular to the global z axis using geometry nodes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, geometry, extrude

[image]

I am new to Geo nodes. I have converted the edges of the road to curve and then used curve line to get faces, then used extrude mesh node to extrude individual faces along z axis, but I want the faces to be perpendicular to Global Z so that I can use them either as buildings themselves or as base for buildings as this is mountain terrain and very uneven. Can someone pls help with this?

U can also think of this as connected stairs along a curve but steps have random height.

If u can further develop this to UV unwrap this and apply some building/shop texture or Use them as bases and add buildings as instances on top, it would be super helpful. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to think of doing it this way:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked, now i need to figure out the UV mapping to apply the building texture